# Creating List in z3 using function

Tags: z3, smt

I'm trying to convert this piece of pseudocode to SMT-LIB language, but I got stuck.

```
List function my_fun(int x)
{
    list = nil
    for(i in 1 to x):
        if(some_condition_on_i)
            list.concat(i)
    return list
}
```

what I've done so far is this:

```
(declare-const l1 (List Int))
(define-fun my_fun ((x Int)) (List Int)
    (forall ((t Int))
        (ite (and (some_condition_on_t) (< t x)) (insert t l1) l1 )
        )
    )
)
```

which I know it is wrong, and does not work. can you help me to understand how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMT-LIB models logic, where variables are always immutable; your code, on the other hand, appears to be imperative, i.e. variables such as `list` and `i` are mutable. This crucial difference will be the biggest challenge in encoding your program and the challenge of reasoning about imperative programs has sparked research tools such as [Dafny](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny), [Boogie](https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie), or [Viper](http://viper.ethz.ch/)

Here are a few pointers:

- `(insert t l1)` represents a new list, obtained by inserting `t` into `l1`. It will *not* modify `l1` (and there is no way to modify l1 since it is a logical variable)
- A logical *forall* is a boolean formula (it evaluates to *true* or *false*), it is not a statement that you can execute (e.g. for its side effects)
- If the value of `x` were statically known (i.e. if it were `5`), then you could unroll the loop (here in pseudo-code):

  ```
  l0 := Nil
  l1 := ite(condition(1), insert(1, l0), l0)
  l2 := ite(condition(2), insert(2, l1), l1)
  ...
  l4 := ite(condition(4), insert(4, l3), l3)
  ```
- If the value of `x` isn't statically known then you'll most likely either need a *loop invariant* or work with *fix points* in order to account for an unknown number of loop iterations

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer which cleared my mind about how z3 or other logic languages work.