# How to verify loop with z3?

Tags: loops, z3, loop-invariant

I am a beginner user of Z3.  How do I verify a loop (C code) with a loop invariant in Z3?

For ex:

```
int a[10],i;
for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
{    
  a[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089983

Answer (score 1):

Z3 only supports first-order logic with theories. 
You can use a program verification tool to map programs with assertions to logic. 
For example http://rise4fun.com/dafny or http://rise4fun.com/fstar.
Reasonable courses on logic in computer science will also contain material on 
how to write a verification condition generator. These are better starting points for this question.